# How Can I Specify Which Fields I Want To Return From Yahoo Finance API Instead Of Getting All Of Them?

Tags: python, api, finance, yahoo

So I'm able to get 200 fields for a stock symbol using Yahoo Finance API (code is below). Is there a way to specify in the querystring which feilds I want (i.e. earningsDate, epsForward, regularMarketPrice, longName, symbol) instead of returning all of them? It's very slow.

````
    def get_quote1(self, symbol):
        url = "https://apidojo-yahoo-finance-v1.p.rapidapi.com/market/v2/get-quotes"

        querystring = {f"region":"US","symbols":{ symbol }}

        headers = {
            'x-rapidapi-key': "7c0c7fd098mshba615283146b103p11faaejsn835b77f547e3",
            'x-rapidapi-host': "apidojo-yahoo-finance-v1.p.rapidapi.com"
        }

        response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

        # json_data = json.loads(response.text)
        json_data= response.json()
        return(json_data)```
````

Answer (score 0):

A specific endpoint returns specific data according to the param we pass. Generally, we can't change the response; it's predefined. But you can always render the specific things you want.

Also, Yahoo Finance API has a lot of endpoints you can play around with. You will definitely find a best-suited endpoint for you that returns minimum but desired data according to your needs.